# Averaging across both rows and columns allowing for NA

Tags: r

My data frame looks like this:

```
> df
  id u.1t u.2 v.1 v.2
1  A    1  NA   5  NA
2  A    2  NA   4   6
3  A    1   4   5  NA
4  B   10  13  40  NA
5  B   10  12  42  NA
6  B   10  NA  41  NA
```

and I would like to know the `id`-specific means of the `u.*` and the `v.*` columns respectively like this:

```
> mean
  id u.mean v.mean
1  A      2      5
2  B     11     41
```

this is the data

```
df<-data.frame(id=c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),u.1t=c(1,2,1,10,10,10),u.2=c(NA,NA,4,13,12,NA),v.1=c(5,4,5,40,42,41),v.2=c(NA,6,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

As is clear, by introducing NA's, the overall mean is unequal to the mean of the row- or column-means, which is the problem here.

I thought this to be a job for `by`, but it turns out I can't get `by` to do anything but columnwise operations?

Help is greatly appreciated--thanks

Comment: I see you "unaccepted" my answer below. Is there something missing you still need answered?

Comment: no, everything is fine. I was wondering if my final comment would be more accepted, if the post was still "unanswered". Don't bother & thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `by`, try something like this:

```
by(x, x$id, function(x) colMeans(x[,-1], na.rm=TRUE))
```

The output is a bit ugly. While you can tidy it up, I would use the `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(x, .(id), function(x) colMeans(x[,-1], na.rm=TRUE))
```

This doesn't quite achieve what you are after, as it takes the average of each column: it doesn't combine the `u.*` and `v.*` columns. To do that, I would `melt` the data first and then use `plyr`:

```
library(reshape2)
y <- melt(x)
y$variable <- gsub("\\..*", '', y$variable)
y
#   id variable value
#1   A        u     1
#2   A        u     2
#3   A        u     1
#4   B        u    10
#5   B        u    10
#6   B        u    10
#7   A        u    NA
#    (etc)

z <- ddply(y, .(id, variable), summarise, mean = mean(value, na.rm=TRUE))
z
#  id variable mean
#1  A        u    2
#2  A        v    5
#3  B        u   11
#4  B        v   41
```

If you choose to, you can `cast` this back:

```
dcast(z, id~variable)
#  id  u  v
#1  A  2  5
#2  B 11 41
```

Answer (score 0):

Sean got it right. His solution works perfect.

But, since pattern replacement in variable names often is inconvenient, not applicable (as is in my case--not the example), or simply not everyone's cup of tea, one might as well introduce a new factor to differentiate the `u's`from the `v's`. `cast` gives the answer rightaway (no need for `plyr`):

```
require(reshape2)

y<-melt(df)
y$x[y$variable %in% c("u.1t","u.2")]<-"u"
y$x[y$variable %in% c("v.1","v.2")]<-"v"
y 
#   id variable value x
#1   A     u.1t     1 u
#2   A     u.1t     2 u
#3   A     u.1t     1 u
#4   B     u.1t    10 u
#5   B     u.1t    10 u
# ...
#22  B      v.2    NA v
#23  B      v.2    NA v
#24  B      v.2    NA v

dcast(y,y$id~x,mean, na.rm=T)
#  y$id  u  v
#1    A  2  5
#2    B 11 41
```

There is even no need to factor the newly created column `y$x`

```
> sapply(y, class)
        id    variable       value           x 
  "factor"    "factor"   "numeric" "character"
```